# How can I detect object which in specific area with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, bounding-box

I am trying to detect some objects with Tensorflow. However, I only want to detect objects in a specific area in the main image. For example:

Here my example area:

The large red framed area is my main image. But I only want to detect objects which in the "content" field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfSI2.png)

Actually, I developed a method like this. I find the center point of the detected object and check if the center point is within this area. If the center of the object is within the specified region, tensorflow takes the detected object into a rectangle. This method works when I'm going to detect a single object. However, I am faced with the following situation: For example, one object is inside the desired region and another object is outside the desired region. Tensorflow actually detects these two objects and adds them to a list. When Tensorflow wants to show the object in the desired region, it necessarily frames all the detected objects in the list. In short, when a single object is detected, objects outside the marked area are also detected and added to the list, but they are ignored and a rectangle is not drawn. However, if an object is detected within the marked area, this time a rectangle is drawn on the object outside the marked area. How do I prevent this?

There is a part for draw boxes:

```
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=3,
        min_score_thresh=0.2)
```

In this part, I actually send all detected objects to the function because I don't know which object is the correct one in the list.

And here the visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array function:

```
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    boxes,
    classes,
    scores,
    category_index,
    instance_masks=None,
    instance_boundaries=None,
    keypoints=None,
    use_normalized_coordinates=False,
    max_boxes_to_draw=2,
    min_score_thresh=.5,
    agnostic_mode=False,
    line_thickness=4,
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
    skip_scores=False,
    skip_labels=False):
  """Overlay labeled boxes on an image with formatted scores and label names.

  This function groups boxes that correspond to the same location
  and creates a display string for each detection and overlays these
  on the image. Note that this function modifies the image in place, and returns
  that same image.

 Args:
    image: uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3)
    boxes: a numpy array of shape [N, 4]
    classes: a numpy array of shape [N]. Note that class indices are 1-based,
      and match the keys in the label map.
    scores: a numpy array of shape [N] or None.  If scores=None, then
      this function assumes that the boxes to be plotted are groundtruth
      boxes and plot all boxes as black with no classes or scores.
    category_index: a dict containing category dictionaries (each holding
      category index `id` and category name `name`) keyed by category indices.
    instance_masks: a numpy array of shape [N, image_height, image_width] with
      values ranging between 0 and 1, can be None.
    instance_boundaries: a numpy array of shape [N, image_height, image_width]
      with values ranging between 0 and 1, can be None.
    keypoints: a numpy array of shape [N, num_keypoints, 2], can
      be None
    use_normalized_coordinates: whether boxes is to be interpreted as
      normalized coordinates or not.
    max_boxes_to_draw: maximum number of boxes to visualize.  If None, draw
      all boxes.
    min_score_thresh: minimum score threshold for a box to be visualized
    agnostic_mode: boolean (default: False) controlling whether to evaluate in
      class-agnostic mode or not.  This mode will display scores but ignore
      classes.
    line_thickness: integer (default: 4) controlling line width of the boxes.
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color: box color for visualizing groundtruth
      boxes
    skip_scores: whether to skip score when drawing a single detection
    skip_labels: whether to skip label when drawing a single detection

  Returns:
    uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3) with overlaid boxes.
  """
  # Create a display string (and color) for every box location, group any boxes
  # that correspond to the same location.
  box_to_display_str_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  box_to_color_map = collections.defaultdict(str)
  box_to_instance_masks_map = {}
  box_to_instance_boundaries_map = {}
  box_to_keypoints_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  if not max_boxes_to_draw:
    max_boxes_to_draw = boxes.shape[0]
  for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
    if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
      box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
      if instance_masks is not None:
        box_to_instance_masks_map[box] = instance_masks[i]
      if instance_boundaries is not None:
        box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box] = instance_boundaries[i]
      if keypoints is not None:
        box_to_keypoints_map[box].extend(keypoints[i])
      if scores is None:
        box_to_color_map[box] = groundtruth_box_visualization_color
      else:
        display_str = ''
        if not skip_labels:
          if not agnostic_mode:
            if classes[i] in category_index.keys():
              class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
            else:
              class_name = 'N/A'
            display_str = str(class_name)
        if not skip_scores:
          if not display_str:
            display_str = '{}%'.format(int(100*scores[i]))
          else:
            display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(display_str, int(100*scores[i]))
        box_to_display_str_map[box].append(display_str)
        if agnostic_mode:
          box_to_color_map[box] = 'DarkOrange'
        else:
          box_to_color_map[box] = STANDARD_COLORS[
              classes[i] % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]

  # Draw all boxes onto image.
  for box, color in box_to_color_map.items():
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box
    if instance_masks is not None:
      draw_mask_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_instance_masks_map[box],
          color=color
      )
    if instance_boundaries is not None:
      draw_mask_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box],
          color='red',
          alpha=1.0
      )
    draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(
        image,
        ymin,
        xmin,
        ymax,
        xmax,
        color=color,
        thickness=line_thickness,
        display_str_list=box_to_display_str_map[box],
        use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates)
    if keypoints is not None:
      draw_keypoints_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_keypoints_map[box],
          color=color,
          radius=line_thickness / 2,
          use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates)

  return image
```

In the above function the name "draw_bounding_box_on_image_array" calls another function.

```
def draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(image,
                                     ymin,
                                     xmin,
                                     ymax,
                                     xmax,
                                     color='red',
                                     thickness=4,
                                     display_str_list=(),
                                     use_normalized_coordinates=True):
  """Adds a bounding box to an image (numpy array).

  Bounding box coordinates can be specified in either absolute (pixel) or
  normalized coordinates by setting the use_normalized_coordinates argument.

  Args:
    image: a numpy array with shape [height, width, 3].
    ymin: ymin of bounding box.
    xmin: xmin of bounding box.
    ymax: ymax of bounding box.
    xmax: xmax of bounding box.
    color: color to draw bounding box. Default is red.
    thickness: line thickness. Default value is 4.
    display_str_list: list of strings to display in box
                      (each to be shown on its own line).
    use_normalized_coordinates: If True (default), treat coordinates
      ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax as relative to the image.  Otherwise treat
      coordinates as absolute.
  """
  image_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert('RGB')
  draw_bounding_box_on_image(image_pil, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, color,
                             thickness, display_str_list,
                             use_normalized_coordinates)
  np.copyto(image, np.array(image_pil))
```

Finally, this function calls another function called "draw_bounding_box_on_image".

```
def draw_bounding_box_on_image(image,
                               ymin,
                               xmin,
                               ymax,
                               xmax,
                               color='red',
                               thickness=4,
                               display_str_list=(),
                               use_normalized_coordinates=True):
  """Adds a bounding box to an image.

  Bounding box coordinates can be specified in either absolute (pixel) or
  normalized coordinates by setting the use_normalized_coordinates argument.

  Each string in display_str_list is displayed on a separate line above the
  bounding box in black text on a rectangle filled with the input 'color'.
  If the top of the bounding box extends to the edge of the image, the strings
  are displayed below the bounding box.

  Args:
    image: a PIL.Image object.
    ymin: ymin of bounding box.
    xmin: xmin of bounding box.
    ymax: ymax of bounding box.
    xmax: xmax of bounding box.
    color: color to draw bounding box. Default is red.
    thickness: line thickness. Default value is 4.
    display_str_list: list of strings to display in box
                      (each to be shown on its own line).
    use_normalized_coordinates: If True (default), treat coordinates
      ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax as relative to the image.  Otherwise treat
      coordinates as absolute.
  """
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
  im_width, im_height = image.size
  if use_normalized_coordinates:
    (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                                  ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
  else:
    (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  draw.line([(left, top), (left, bottom), (right, bottom),
             (right, top), (left, top)], width=thickness, fill=color)
  try:
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 24)
  except IOError:
    font = ImageFont.load_default()

  # If the total height of the display strings added to the top of the bounding
  # box exceeds the top of the image, stack the strings below the bounding box
  # instead of above.
  display_str_heights = [font.getsize(ds)[1] for ds in display_str_list]
  # Each display_str has a top and bottom margin of 0.05x.
  total_display_str_height = (1 + 2 * 0.05) * sum(display_str_heights)

  if top > total_display_str_height:
    text_bottom = top
  else:
    text_bottom = bottom + total_display_str_height
  # Reverse list and print from bottom to top.
  for display_str in display_str_list[::-1]:
    text_width, text_height = font.getsize(display_str)
    margin = np.ceil(0.05 * text_height)
    draw.rectangle(
        [(left, text_bottom - text_height - 2 * margin), (left + text_width,
                                                          text_bottom)],
        fill=color)
    draw.text(
        (left + margin, text_bottom - text_height - margin),
        display_str,
        fill='black',
        font=font)
    text_bottom -= text_height - 2 * margin
```

As far as I understand, this function draws a rectangle using the coordinates of the detected object. Can you please help with this issue?

Comment: You say you want to detect object in a specific area of an image. If this is a static area(?), hence you are always looking in that specific area, the easiest way in my opinion is to use region of interest (ROI). So, find the coordinates of the ROI in the image and perform object detection on the ROI instead.

Comment: I already tried this. Instead of checking the whole picture, I checked only the region I specified in the picture. However, there is a problem: If it finds an object in the ROI, I want to draw a line from the center of that object to the center of the whole picture. Because, I want to find the distance from the center of the object to the center of the main picture. However, when I use the method you mentioned, the coordinates get mixed up and I can't get the right result.

Comment: But as far as I understand there is no other solution. I need to do as you said and somehow get the coordinates according to the dimensions and location of the main image.